# Add Annocation in Alamofire closure

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview

I'm trying to add annocations on map which locations and title label's coming from server and I try this so for

```
Services.MyService(pagingParams: pagingparam1, completed: {ret in
        self.getAdverts = ret
        for elements in self.getAdverts{
              
                let coordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(elements.LOCATIONS[0])!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(elements.LOCATIONS[1])!)
                pinCords.coordinate = coordinates
                pinCords.title = String(elements.PRICE!)
                self.map.addAnnotation(pinCords)
           
        }


    })
```

And in MKMapViewDelegate I try to show annocations :

```
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       if annotation is MKUserLocation == true
    {

        return nil
    }
    
           let av = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "offercount")

    let annoIcon = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    annoIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   
    annoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "cancel-red")
    
    lbl.text = annotation.title!

    lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    lbl.textColor = .white
    lbl.alpha = 1
    lbl.numberOfLines = 1
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    lbl.layer.masksToBounds = true
    


    av.backgroundColor = AreaColors.advertColor
    av.canShowCallout = true
    av.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: annoIcon.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.size.width + 4, height: 20)
    av.layer.cornerRadius = av.layer.bounds.height/4
    
    let pinlbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:av.layer.bounds.width/2-10, y:av.layer.bounds.height-10, width:20, height:20))
    pinlbl.layer.masksToBounds = true
    pinlbl.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    pinlbl.backgroundColor = AreaColors.advertColor
    av.addSubview(pinlbl)
    av.addSubview(annoIcon)
    av.addSubview(lbl)


    return av
}
```

There is a label in green view which image is below
[image]

Only 1 `annocation.title` is appear others don't. But when I click to any annocation I can see the title.

I think the problem is async closure but I really don't fix it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're reusing your `lbl` and adding it to each annotation, hence you're only seeing it in the last annotation. You will have to create new `UILabel` for each annotation and add it as a subview the same way you're doing with `pinlbl`, as what you have now is removing `lbl` from the previous annotation and re-adding it to the next one until it stops and persists it in the last annotation on the map.

Just change the following

```
annoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "cancel-red")
// create new label here
let lbl = UILabel()

// the rest of your code can stay the same
```

Comment: Thanks I did and work. I use annocation.title to send price datas to annocations and when I click to annocation title is appears. I just use it to send data to in it. How can I remove it?

Comment: You don't need to remove it, just create new instance of `UILabel` for the title of your ** MKAnnotationView**. It is fine to pass data in the `annotation.title` look at my updated answer.